# NewRelic: HOWTO get only the LAST data per FullHostName (Regardless of when queried)

Tags: monitoring, newrelic

In New Relic Infrastructure monitoring (not alerting) I am trying to get the latest CPU and Memory, per FullHostName:

```
SELECT fullHostname,processorCount,memoryTotalBytes/1073741824 from SystemSample where fullHostname LIKE 'serverconvention%' COMPARE WITH 1 week ago
```

When the above runs I get only 10 servers out of hundreds.
When I run the below choice I get more than 20 entries ***per server***:

```
SELECT fullHostname,processorCount,memoryTotalBytes/1073741824 from SystemSample where fullHostname LIKE 'serverconvention' COMPARE WITH 1 week ago LIMIT Max
```

So how do I limit the data to only *ONE set of values PER FullHostName*, only the LATEST data (regardless of *when* the latest data came in)?

Comment: -The reason this is an issue is because the servers don't all report in at the same time, and the amount of time thousands do precludes setting a specific "within one day" narrowing of the data. Plus, once this work I would be able to see when a server hasn't checked in for a while too! Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

`SELECT latest(processorCount), latest(memoryTotalBytes)/1073741824 FROM SystemSample where fullHostname LIKE 'serverconvention%' facet fullHostname COMPARE WITH 1 week ago LIMIT MAX`

This will give you the latest processorCount/memory + faceting is essentially grouping - so that should break it down for each unique host you are targeting.

Comment: It's also worthwhile to note that if no `since` clause is provided, the default is `since 60 minutes ago` - You may want to specify `since 1 day ago` or longer in the query.

Comment: 'SELECT latest(processorCount), latest(memoryTotalBytes)/1073741824 FROM SystemSample where fullHostname LIKE '%serverconvention%' facet fullHostname LIMIT MAX' seems to work best with the Dashboard setting the time queried (I never could get compare to work here)